# How Can I Use $wpdb in PayPal IPN file?

Tags: wpdb, api, paypal

I'm currently writing a plugin that requires the PayPal IPN, since the IPN is not inside the main plugin file, I have no way to use $wpdb. If you know a way to do this that will work with all WordPress installations it would really help me!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Use the ajax api: http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

If you let all your ajax calls go through this you will have access to all WP functions.

Also take a look at these: http://www.james-vandyne.com/process-paypal-ipn-requests-through-wordpress/

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/paypal-framework/

Don't know if what you want is in there, but worth a look.

Comment: Yeah, I could convert my ajax loads to use this method, I am using this method with other ajax calls but the main problem is the PayPal IPN, I have to get the results back from paypal, then post to the database.

Comment: I see, I added 2 more links. Your question is much clearer now

Comment: I believe I've read the article at http://www.james-vandyne.com the only problem I have with that is it requires url rewriting.

Comment: The process can be much simplified by just using the INIT hook and checking for a $_GET variable.